# Hot to re-active preventDefault function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, preventdefault, reactive

When user clicked on submit button, I need to check some validations before submition. If entered data is not valid page should not be submit.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#colomnChange").submit(function(e) {
    var testA = 1;
    if (testA == 1) {
      testA = 2;
      //e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }

  });
});
```

I can stop the submition using priventDefault function in js. But again user clicked on submit button after correct the wrong data, page should be submit well. How can I re-active the default function.

Comment: try move `var testA = 1;` outside the submit function

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: you always go into the first `if` (because you set the variable to 1 then check if it equals 1, which is always true)
Change `testA = 1 to testA = 2` and your event will go into the `else` which does not have the `preventDefault()` method so your event will carry on